# Samba create_mode and directory_mode not working in ubuntu18

Tags: samba, ubuntu-18.04

We are installing samba on **Ubuntu18.04** and samba has default version **4.7.4-ubuntu**

Configured **samba** for a share and set **create_mode** as **0664** and **directory_mode** as **0700**:

```
[Sharemike]
  path = /opt/shareonly
  create mask = 0664
  directory mask = 0700
  browseable = yes
  writeable = yes
  comment = sharing /opt/sharepublic folder
  read only = no
  valid users = mike
```

Mounted share locally. Able to create file and directory using smbclient and also with mike user account.
But when checked the **directory_mode** and **creare_mode**, they are showing **755** and **755**

Also tried below combinations in **smb.conf** but did nto work:

```
inherit permissions = yes
unix extensions = no
obey pam restrictions = no
force create mode = 0664
force directory mode = 2700
force user = mike
```

In **Ubuntu16** it is working as configured in samba.

Can anyone explain why this behaviour in Ubuntu18?

Comment: Any thoughts??
Still facing issue